# Can I implement round half to even?

Tags: ruby, rounding

I need to do [round half to even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) on floats, i.e.,

1. if the value is half-way between two integers (tie-breaking, fraction part of y is exactly 0.5) round to the nearest even integer,
2. else, standard round (which is Round to nearest Integer in Ruby).

These are some results, for example:

```
0.5=>0
1.49=>1
1.5=>2
2.5=>2
2.51=>3
3.5=>4
```

Comment: https://twitter.com/jashkenas/status/230028913013846016

Comment: In floating point arithmetik, there no such thing as "exactly". even simple calculations can lead to things like 1.50000000000001

Comment: @Meier 0.5 in decimal representation is exactly 0.1 In binary representation.

Comment: @sawa yes, but when you somehow calculated your number, you can easily get an difference in the last bit.

Comment: @Meier: Not so. Any float has an exact value, and as it happens, the result of the round-half-to-even operation on a float (rounding to the nearest integer) is *always* exactly representable - at least, assuming IEEE 754 floating-point, so that operation can be performed exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reopen the Float class to create a round_half_to_even function :

```
class Float
  def round_half_to_even(precision)
    if self % 1 == 0.5
      floor = self.to_i.to_f
      return floor % 2 == 0 ? floor : floor + 1
    else
      return self.round(precision)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The question did not ask for a precision and you are unnecessarily complicating your code by adding that "feature". As is, `x = 2.2.round_half_to_even(0) #=> 2`, but `x = 2.5.round_half_to_even(0) #=> 2.0`. Suppose the next statement were `y=(x+1)/2`? In one case `y #=> 1`, in the other `y #=>1.5`.  Including "precision" makes for a messy fix. Also, you don't need either `self.` or either `return`. I suggest you simplify to `def round_half_to_even; if self % 1 == 0.5; floor = to_i; floor.even? ? floor : floor + 1; else; round; end; end`.

Comment: I believe this fails for negative numbers, which is a big reason to use round-to-even in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

The `BigDecimal` class has the rounding mode *half to even* already implemented. You just have to set the `ROUND_MODE` to `:half_even` with [`BigDecimal.mode`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-c-mode) method:

```
require 'bigdecimal'

def round_half_to_even(float)
  BigDecimal.mode(BigDecimal::ROUND_MODE, :half_even)
  BigDecimal.new(float, 0).round
end
```

Or by using the [`round`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-round) with some arguments:

```
require 'bigdecimal'

def round_half_to_even(float)
  BigDecimal.new(float, 0).round(0, :half_even).to_i
end
```

Please note that `BigDecimal#round` returns an `Integer` when used without arguments, but a `BigDecimal` when used with arguments. Therefore the need to call `to_i` in the second example but not in the first.

Answer (score 0):

```
def round_half_to_even f
  q, r = f.divmod(2.0)
  q * 2 +
  case
  when r <= 0.5 then 0
  when r >= 1.5 then 2
  else 1
  end
end

round_half_to_even(0.5) # => 0
round_half_to_even(1.49) # => 1
round_half_to_even(1.5) # => 2
round_half_to_even(2.5) # => 2
round_half_to_even(2.51) # => 3
round_half_to_even(3.5) # => 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
def round_half_to_even(f)
  floor = f.to_i
  return f.round unless f==floor+0.5
  floor.odd? ? f.ceil : floor
end

round_half_to_even(2.4) #=> 2
round_half_to_even(2.6) #=> 3
round_half_to_even(3.6) #=> 4
round_half_to_even(2.5) #=> 2
round_half_to_even(3.5) #=> 4
```