# Round a float up if positive, down if negative, to a set number of decimal places

Tags: ruby, math

I'm dealing with elapsed hours that should always round up to 1 decimal place, but time in the past needs to round down (so 0.33 hours is 0.4, -0.33 hours is -0.4).

I've briefly written the following but it feels inelegant. Is there a more obvious or more railsy way to do this?

```
def ceil_to_digits(n, digits = 1)
  digits = 10.0 ** digits
  if n > 0                   
    return (n * digits).ceil / digits   
  else                       
    return (n * digits).floor / digits  
  end   
end

n = 0.333
ceil_to_digits(n, 1) => 0.4
ceil_to_digits(n, 2) => 0.34

n = -0.333
ceil_to_digits(n, 1) => -0.4
ceil_to_digits(n, 2) => -0.34
```

Comment: Do you need 0.33 to round to 0.4 (and -0.33 to round to -0.4) - in which case maybe rounding isn't the correct term?

Comment: @KevinSylvestre Yes, UP if positive, DOWN if negative. I've changed the example to 0.33 to make that clearer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BigDecimal` has various different [rounding modes](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-c-mode). In this case `ROUND_UP` would solve your problem:

```
require 'bigdecimal'

def ceil_to_digits(n, digits = 1)
  BigDecimal.new(n, 0).round(digits, :up)
end

n = 0.333
ceil_to_digits(n, 1) #=> 0.4
ceil_to_digits(n, 2) #=> 0.34

n = -0.333
ceil_to_digits(n, 1) #=> -0.4
ceil_to_digits(n, 2) #=> -0.34
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Actually I showed you this trick [before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35365302/2483313)... ;-)

Comment: I did see that, as I upvoted it, but how can you expect me to remember? That was ages ago.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it by using the round function:

```
(n * 10).round / 10.0
```

Furthermore `round` takes the number of digits:

```
n.round(1)

+0.37.round(1) # +0.4
-0.37.round(1) # -0.4
```

For more info: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Float.html#method-i-round

**Edit**

Given you are looking for a non-standard rounding not much you can do to improve your snippet. Maybe:

```
((n * 10.0).send(n > 0 ? :ceil : :floor)) / 10.0
```

Comment: I need to always round UP, so when 0.34 comes along it becomes 0.4. I'll change my question to make that more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I think your method is fine. If you want to shorten it, you could write the following.

```
def ceil_to_digits(n, digits = 1)
  x = 10.0 ** digits
  (n*x).send(n > 0 ? :ceil : :floor)/x
end

n = 0.333
ceil_to_digits(n, 1) #=> 0.4
ceil_to_digits(n, 2) #=> 0.34

n = -0.333
ceil_to_digits(n, 1) #=> -0.4
ceil_to_digits(n, 2) #=> -0.34
```